# What do the "shiwat" and "rhiwat" columns mean in output of netstat -v?

Tags: command-line

The output of `netstat -v` includes the following column labels:

```
Proto  Recv-Q  Send-Q  Local Address  Foreign Address  (state)  rhiwat  shiwat  pid  epid  state  options
```

`man netstat` does not explain the meaning of the "rhiwat" and "shiwat" columns, and I have also been unable to find an explanation in search engines or here/on stackoverflow.

What do the numbers in these columns mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the [BSD `netstat` man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=netstat&sektion=1) and I see the following:

```
R-HIWA    Receive buffer high water mark, in bytes.
S-HIWA    Send buffer high  water mark, in bytes.
```